# Computer Level 2 Bug Question

Tags: candy-box

I tried it several times now, loading and performing a lvl 2 bug to increase my lp production. In the Wiki i read that the cap rate is at 10k lp/s but my rate won't reach more than 143 lp/s. I even had 2 lvl 2 bugs in a row but it didnt change anything. Am I doing something wrong or is it just pure luck?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to plant more lollipops in order to reach that rate. I planted nearly 1.75 million lollipops to reach 10klp/s. And just to check, but you're getting the bug that specifically says it has increased production, right?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I wasn't aware that I have to plant mor lp's!

Comment: Glad I could help! If this answer fixed your problem, please hit the accept button :)